# C - Need to print a pyramid with #'s when the user inputs a height

Tags: c, input, user-input, cs50

I need to have a user input a height value, if it's higher than 23 or less than 0 it should ask again. It should then print a pyramid of #'s sort of like the stairs at the end of a game of mario bros (with 2 hashtags on the right side, see example). The problem is that the code runs and doesn't print any #'s, the code just ends. This is for an online course so please don't just post the code, if you are going to post the full code please explain it.

> Pyramid example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fyg2ls0eml7asi/Screenshot%20from%202014-03-20%2002%3A15%3A08.png
>
> Flowchart that I followed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X77oT.png

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "cs50.h"

int main(void){
    //int h = 0;
    printf("Enter height between 0 and 23: ");
    int h = scanf("%d", &h);
    while (h < 0 || h > 23){
        printf("Retry: ");
        h = scanf("%d", &h);
    }
    int l = 1;
    if (h == 0){
        //printf("ln21\n"); //Debug
        return;
    }
    int s = h - 1;
    int b = l + 1;
    if (s == 0){
        if (b == 0){
            printf("\n");
    h = h - 1;
    l = l + 1;
    if (h == 0){
        return;
    }
        }
    }
    else{
    printf("#");
    b = b - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: see this answer: [Mario Pyramid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961481/creating-a-mario-style-pyramid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int height = 8;//Number of repetitions of basic.
    int max_width = height + 1;//Number of block(#) in the largest display
    int i, j, w;
    for(i = 0; i < height; ++i){
        printf("%*s", max_width -(i+2), "");//Print a space in front of the block
        for(w = 0; w < i+2; ++w){
            printf("#");//display a block of each floor
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int height = 8;
    int max_width = height + 1;
    char wall[max_width + 1];
    int i;
    memset(wall, '#', sizeof(wall)-1);// make a block of maximum.
    wall[sizeof(wall)-1] = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i < height; ++i){
        printf("%*.*s\n", max_width, i+2, wall);//View of block size and the required blank
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works. But you didn't explain it at all.

Comment: How can I set "int height = scanf(not sure what to put here);"

Comment: @SeanBehan You need to go lookup `scanf`. It does not return what you think it does.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yeah, I just did that. lol I feel stupid. The code works now. I'll update the question code.

Comment: Just realized that you dont need j in the first one.

Comment: @SeanBehan _you dont need j in the first one_ : yes, It was prepared as a double loop, but had forgot to remove replaced by `w`.